# SQL Query for Count and Max without using Ranks or Top

Tags: sql-server

I want to know in each department the user who registered the most, closed the 
most. This data is distributed in 3 tables - Department and Closed are in BATCH
table, registered_by in STORE table, and username in ACCOUNT table.

I'm trying to get this info using count and max aggregate functions.

Here is the query I have written:

```
 SELECT
     b.department_id, 
     s.regsitered_by, 
     b.closed_by, 
     a.username,
     COUNT(s.regsitered_by) As "Total Regsitered",
     COUNT(b.closed_by) As "Total Closed"

    FROM [db].[store] as s
    LEFT JOIN [db].[batch] b on b.id = s.batch_id
    LEFT JOIN [db].[accounts] as a on a.id = b.closed_by

    WHERE registered_by = (select max(regsitered_by)from [db].[store]) AND
    closed_by = (select max(closed_by)from [db].[batch])

    group by  
     b.department_id, 
     s.regsitered_by, 
     b.closed_by, 
     a.username
```

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

I was also trying to use a temp table to save the results though that wasn't to much help either

```
 SELECT
     b.department_id, 
     s.regsitered_by, 
     b.closed_by, 
     a.username,
     COUNT(s.regsitered_by) AS "Total Regsitered",
     COUNT(b.closed_by) AS "Total Closed"

     INTO #TEMP1

    FROM [db].[store] AS s
    LEFT JOIN [db].[batch] AS b ON b.id = s.batch_id
    LEFT JOIN [db].[accounts] AS a ON a.id = b.closed_by

    GROUP BY
     b.department_id, 
     s.regsitered_by, 
     b.closed_by, 
     a.username

    SELECT *
    FROM #temp1
    WHERE registered_by = (SELECT MAX(regsitered_by)FROM [db].[store]) AND
    closed_by = (SELECT MAX(closed_by)From [db].[batch])

    DROP TABLE #temp1
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant tables DDL statements, some sample data (preferably as DML statements) and desired results.

Comment: **registered_by = (select max(regsitered_by)from [db].[store]) AND
    closed_by = (select max(closed_by)from [db].[batch])** You're comparing a count with a user according to what I see. So you won't get any records from this. The user who registered the most may not be the user who closed the most. So do you want all that info in one row or two separate rows?

Comment: @Sam - yes, I get what you mean. You are right, this approach does not work when the same person is not highest.

Answer (score 0):

In where clause,you are checking for below condition..

```
WHERE registered_by = (select max(regsitered_by)from [db].[store]) AND
closed_by = (select max(closed_by)from [db].[batch])
```

this will be applied prior to count,so you may not get accurate results..Move the clause to having

```
 SELECT
     b.department_id, 
     s.regsitered_by, 
     b.closed_by, 
     a.username,
     COUNT(s.regsitered_by) As "Total Regsitered",
     COUNT(b.closed_by) As "Total Closed"
    FROM [db].[store] as s
    LEFT JOIN [db].[batch] b on b.id = s.batch_id
    LEFT JOIN [db].[accounts] as a on a.id = b.closed_by
    group by  
     b.department_id, 
     s.regsitered_by, 
     b.closed_by, 
     a.username
having 
 COUNT(s.regsitered_by)=(select max(regsitered_by)from [db].[store])
 and
 COUNT(s.closed_by)=(select max(closed_by)from [db].[batch])
```

Comment: you should have AND / OR between the two having conditions I guess

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but unfortunately this change does not give any results!

Answer (score 0):

No ranking allowed (`rank`, `dense_rank`, `row_number`)? Well, here is how to get the most closing person(s) per department then:

```
select counts.department_id, counts.closed_by
from
(
  select department_id, closed_by, count(*) as cnt
  from batch
  group by department_id, closed_by
) counts
join
(
  select department_id, max(cnt) as cnt
  from
  (
    select department_id, count(*) as cnt
    from batch
    group by department_id, closed_by
  ) counts
) maxcounts on maxcounts.department_id = counts.department_id 
            and maxcounts.cnt = counts.cnt
```

Do the same for `department_id, registered_by`, for which you must join the two tables `batch` and `store`.

Then:

```
select 
  coalesce(c.department_id, r.department_id) as department_id,
  (select username from account a where a.id = c.closed_by) as closer,
  (select username from account a where a.id = c.registered_by) as registerer
from (<close_by query>) c
full outer join (<registered_by query>) r on r.department_id = c.department_id;
```

I should add that this is not optimal in case there are several maximum closers or registerers per department. Say for department X we have the following registerers:

```
user   cnt
emp1   20
emp2   30
emp3   30
```

and the following closers;

```
user   cnt
emp1   15
emp2   10
emp4   15
```

Then we get:

```
dept   max_registerer   max_closer
X      emp2             emp1
X      emp2             emp4
X      emp3             emp1
X      emp3             emp4
```

So you may want to aggregate this result to get

```
dept   max_registerer   max_closer
X      emp2, emp3       emp1, emp4
```

instead for instance. (If so, look up how to mimic GROUP_CONCAT in SQL Server.)